# BrowseForfolder command not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, browser, vbscript, 7zip

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
BrowseForfolder="Yes"
RunProgram="Patch.bat"
DeleteTempFiles="No"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

the above code exist in my config.txt file .BrowseForfolder command is not working when i try to run my exe file.(i means the window dialog not appearing to select the path.). directly it is executing my 'Patch.bat' script. Kindly help me on this regard.

Comment: What language is this? It's not batch.

Comment: It's not VBScript either.

Comment: 7-zip SFX script syntax? Several of those directives are not listed in the  documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i used 7zS.sfx for self extracting.but this 7z sfx won't conatin all the properties which i mentioned in the program (i.e BrowseForfolder,DeleteTempFiles).so i used the modeified version of 7z sfx.which is 7zsd.sfx it solved the issue.